# GStreamer for Android MP3 Files

Tags: android, mp3, gstreamer

I'm testing the demo at,
http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Android+tutorial+5%3A+A+Complete+media+player

I only changed the permissions to allow reading from the SD card, and when I try to play a MP3 file, it says, `amcaudiodec-omxgooglemp3decoder0: Internal data stream error`. Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Edit: Ogg files work fine.